# Add quantity for every the same Client and Product in Django

Tags: python, django

I have 3 models, CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail, Customer and Product model, if Customer1 buy a product for example, Meat. it will save in CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail and if that Customer1 add another Meat Product, instead of adding another record to the database it will simply just add quantity.

this is my views.py

```
def batchaddtocart(request):
    userID = request.POST.get("userID")
    client = Customer(id=userID)
    vegetables_id = request.POST.get("id")

    v = Product(id=vegetables_id)
    price = request.POST.get("price")
    discount = request.POST.get("discount_price")

    insert, create = CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail.objects.get_or_create(
        profile=client,
        products=v,
        unitprice=price,
        quantity=1,
        discounted_amount=discount,
        discounted_unitprice=discount,
    )

    order_qs = CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail.objects.filter\
        (
            profile=client,
            products=v,
            unitprice=price,
            quantity=1,
            discounted_amount=discount,
            discounted_unitprice=discount
        )
    for order in order_qs:
        if order.profile == client and order.products == v:
            insert.quantity += 1
            print(insert.quantity)
            insert.save()
    insert.save()
```

this is my models.py

```
class CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Customer, 
                                on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                verbose_name="Client Account")
    products = models.ForeignKey(Product, 
                                                on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                                verbose_name="Product")
    quantity = models.IntegerField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True, default=1)

class Product(models.Model):
      product = models.CharField(max_length=500)

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="profile", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    contactNumber = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
```

I did not encounter an error but the functionality I wanted did not work. it does not add additional quantity even if the same product is added to the list purchased by Customer1.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What errors have you encountered?

Comment: this is my updated code

Comment: just change floatfield to integer

Comment: I changed it now but the error is still the same

Comment: Where and how are you accessing the `quantity` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `get_or_create` method, it will create a new entry whenever at least one parameter is different enough to did not match any registered value. So, if you pass the quantity parameter equals 1, it always will create a new entry when quantity is 2+, for instance.

You should filter first with only the "fixed" parameters and create a new entry if you get nothing. Otherwise, just increment quantity.

Something like this:

```py
order = None
order_qs = CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail.objects.filter\
        (
            profile=client,
            products=v,
            unitprice=price,
            discounted_amount=discount,
            discounted_unitprice=discount
        )

if not order_qs:
    order = CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail.objects.create(
        profile=client,
        products=v,
        unitprice=price,
        quantity=1,
        discounted_amount=discount,
        discounted_unitprice=discount,
    )
else:
    for order in order_qs:
        if order.profile == client and order.products == v:
            # NOTE: Please, note if you need to check your other parameters too (unityprice, discounted....)
            order.quantity += 1
            print(order.quantity)
            order.save()
```

Answer (score 4):

the problem is in following lines `client = Customer(id=userID)` and `v = Product(id=vegetables_id)` every time your function is called you are creating new customer and product objects instead of using existing objects is your database. replace them with `client,created = Customer.objects.get_or_create(id=userID)` and same for product `v,v_created = Product.objects.get_or_create(id=vegetables_id)`